# Enable jQuery UI Dialog Button when a Valid Label from a jQuery UI Autocomplete is Selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a jQuery UI Dialog Box that contains a jQuery UI Autocomplete input box populated with various labels. The dialog box itself has two buttons in the buttonpane: "Select" and "Cancel." However, I want enable and disable the "Select" button depending upon what the user has currently in the text field of the input box. In other words, the list of available tags that the autocomplete makes use of contains all of the valid options the user can select. So, if they select one of these labels from the autocomplete, the "Select" button will be enabled, allowing them to click it. In addition, if they simply type in the proper label without physically selecting one of the labels from the autocomplete's drop-down box, I still want this "Select" button enabled.

At first, I figured I'd just cross-reference the text currently in the input box each time the input field changed with the list of available labels to see if I should enable the "Select" button, but so far, it hasn't seemed to work. Any suggestions as to how I might accomplish this? Here's what I've tried thus far:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        Select: function() {
            // Carry out some proceedure knowing they've selected a valid label.
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            // Cancels the selection and closes the dialog box.
        }
    },
    closeOnEscape: false,
    create: function(event, ui) {
        var labels = ["Bird", "Boar", "Dog", "Dragon", "Ox", "Tiger"];
        $("#input").autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: labels
        });
        $("#input").change(function() {
            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Select')").button("disable");
            labels.each(function() {
                if($("#input").text() == $(this)) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Select')").button("enable");
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
    },
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    title: "Select Dialog",
    width: 460
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, how about using [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray) to toggle the button? Also, you need to use `$(this).val()` or `this.value` to figure out the value of an `input` element.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        Select: function() {
            // Carry out some proceedure knowing they've selected a valid label.
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            // Cancels the selection and closes the dialog box.
        }
    },
    closeOnEscape: false,
    create: function(event, ui) {
        var labels = ["Bird", "Boar", "Dog", "Dragon", "Ox", "Tiger"];
        $("#input").autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: labels
        });
        $("#input").change(function() {
            var enabled = $.inArray(this.value, labels) >= 0 ? "enable" : "disable";
            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Select')").button(enabled);
        });
    },
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    title: "Select Dialog",
    width: 460
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kcrBB/

---

Per the comment, here's an example with `keyup` instead of change:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function () {
        $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Select')").button("disable");
    },
    buttons: {
        Select: function() {
            // Carry out some proceedure knowing they've selected a valid label.
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            // Cancels the selection and closes the dialog box.
        }
    },
    closeOnEscape: false,
    create: function(event, ui) {
        var labels = ["Bird", "Boar", "Dog", "Dragon", "Ox", "Tiger"];
        $("#input").autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: labels,
            select: function () {
                $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Select')").button("enable");       
            }
        });

        $("#input").keyup(function() {
            var enabled = $.inArray(this.value, labels) >= 0 ? "enable" : "disable";
            $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Select')").button(enabled);
        });
    },
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    title: "Select Dialog",
    width: 460
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kcrBB/16/

Comment: Ah, I see. The one issue I have is that it only triggers the change when you either select one of the labels from the autocomplete (which is perfect) or when the user presses enter after typing. Is there anyway to have it check whenever a key is added or removed? Like rather than using the change event, using the keypress or keyup event?

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. I originally missed disabling the button on the open event, which was throwing me off. The second fiddle you posted does just about what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the user still has to hit a key after they've clicked on one of the autocomplete labels in order to trigger the check. Could this be combined with the `select` event the Autocomplete comes compatible with, too?

Comment: I managed to make `$(".ui-autocomplete").click()` trigger the same check, and it works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @KrisSchouw: Good point. I updated the second example. I would actually use the `select` event instead of binding to `click`.